# Adding and calculating values in pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have pivot_table with code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
...                          "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
...                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
...                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
...                    "C": ["2017", "2017", "2018", "2017",
...                          "2018", "2017", "2018", "2017",
...                          "2017"],
...                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
dataf = df.pivot_table(values="D", index=["A","B"], columns=["C"], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True, dropna=True)
dataf
C       2017    2018    All
A   B           
bar one 4.0     5.0     9
two     13.0    NaN    13
foo one 3.0     2.0     5
two     3.0     3.0     6
All     23.0    10.0   33
```

I want to add new Column after 2018 that will be calculating 2018 / 2017 value. How can I do this?

Comment: Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: 1) post your data, not images of your data 2) use `df.assign` to create a new column

Comment: problem not in creating. I can't call '2018' cause it not in columns name. its in columns values.

Comment: i guess you are dealing with the multi-level columns. Please post a small reproducible sample input data set (as text, so we could copy and paste it) and your desired data set...

Comment: Ty. I am posted